# Interactive web apps with react.js on the server

Tags: javascript, ruby, reactjs, web-frameworks

I'm looking for web framework for **interactive, real-time web apps without writing the Client (Browser), everything will be done by the Server**.

There's such framework - [LiveView](https://dockyard.com/blog/2018/12/12/phoenix-liveview-interactive-real-time-apps-no-need-to-write-javascript) in Phoenix (Elixir/Erlang), see demos below. **I'm looking for something similar in JavaScript/TypeScript or Ruby**.

[image]

How it works, it's better to demonstrate by example. Let's imagine we already have such framework in JavaScript and building an Autocomplete component. It would look almost like React.JS, but with the huge difference - it will be run on the Server:

```
class Autocomplete extends MagicServerSideReactComponent {
  state = { 
    query:       '',
    suggestions: []
  }

  async search(e) {
    const query = e.target.value

    // This whole component runs on the Server, not in the Browser.
    // So it has full access to the Server infrastructure and Database.
    const suggestions = await db.find(`select like '${query}'`)

    this.setState({ query, suggestions })
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <input value={this.state.query} onKeyPress={this.search}/>
      {this.state.suggestions.map((name) => <div>{name}</div>)}
    </div>
  }
}
```

How it works:

```
When rendered first time:

- Autocomplete component get rendered on the Server and final HTML sent 
  to the Browser. 
  The Server remembers the `state` and the Virtual DOM - i.e. it's a 
  statefull Server, not usual Stateless node.js Server.
- Browser gets the HTML and renders it into DOM.

When user type something in the input: 

- Browser serializes the Event and sends it to the Server, 
  something like  `{ method: 'Autocomplete.search', event: '...' }`
- Server get the serialized Event and the previously stored Virtual DOM 
  for the given Web Page.
  Then Server process the Event, and as a result the Virtual DOM 
  on the Server gets updated.
  Then Server finds out the difference between the new and old Virtual DOM 
  and generates the DIFF.
  Then Server sends the DOM DIFF to the Browser
- Browser gets the DOM DIFF and modify its DOM.
  And the user see its Web Page updated with the search suggestions.
```

Do you know any such **web frameworks in JavaScript or Ruby**?

Please don't suggest frameworks that do something like that - but where you have to mutate DOM manually. **Virtual DOM on the Server is important** because it allows to update DOM automatically. It doesn't have to be exactly like React.JS but it should update DOM automatically, like React does.

P.S.

- Why? Because of the first law of distributed systems - "Don't build distributed systems". **It's simpler** to build web app as one instead of distributing it into client and server.
- Latency - yes, nothing is free, you have to pay for the simplicity and the latency will be the price. The interactions would be delayed - to travel to the server and back.
- Performance - yes, Server is not stateless anymore, it's stateful, runs Virtual DOM and consume more resources.

Comment: Did you search the Web for "server side virtual DOM"? What about `ReactDOMServer`? Why doesn't it fit your needs?

Comment: Great! Need to try it))

Comment: @Aurélien as far as I know `ReactDOMServer` does different thing - it renders react into static DOM, usually for initial page load. It does not handles interactivity.

Comment: @AlexeyPetrushin I'm not myself familiar to `ReactDomServer` but it seems that you can `hydrate` a component so that the server-rendered HTML is linked to the server-side state. https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/ServerRendering.md

Comment: You may checkout [ts-liveview](https://github.com/beenotung/ts-liveview), which is heavily inspired by Phoenix Liveview but implemented in Typescript (you can use it with javascript as well). It's not production ready, I'm rewriting in pre-v2 branch for more modulized and flexible structure.

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at marko by ebay (https://markojs.com/docs/server-side-rendering/) but I don't think you can find a framework/library with all your requirements.

> Because of the first law of distributed systems - "Don't build distributed systems". It's simpler to build web app as one instead of distributing it into client and server.

The code you send to user with react or any other single page application framework is defining view. So you shouldn't consider it as a system. It's just html, css, js + user's data

> Virtual DOM on the Server is important because it allows to update DOM
>   automatically.

Why the goal is to update DOM? DOM is just a view of your state/data. And your frontend application is just a mapper/hash function from your state to DOM. So if you only have your state in your server, you kind of have your DOM as well.

**If you don't want to write both server and client**, but still you want to have fancy frontend features with thousands of open source repos, you can try react + firebase.

Comment: Thanks, but `marko` server rendering does only half the story, it only renders the initial state of the page. It does not handles the interactivity.